# "Answer migrated" message not shown in inbox screen in app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app, migration, global-inbox

Today, an [answer of mine](https://meta.superuser.com/a/12835/442468) was migrated from Meta Stack Exchange to Meta Super User. While I do recall seeing a '1' on the inbox icon in the app, I can't see the message itself:

[image]

The message is only visible on the site itself:

[image]

This is probably due to the API not publishing those message types, so I'm not sure if I should tag this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).